# Foreign key / ID that is not assigned

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app with records that contain foreign IDs linking to records other records (belongs_to).

I am aware that index IDs start at 1 by default, and it's common to have a validation in the model that ensures foreign ID values are greater than zero.

In my example, I would like to have the option to not have a foreign ID set (i.e. it is not [yet] linked to a another 'owning' record).

Would it be appropriate to remove the validation from the model, and then set the value of the foreign ID to zero in this case, indicating that it is not assigned?

For some reason, I don't seem to be able to find this stated in documentation anywhere, maybe I'm using the wrong terminology, or it's too obvious to document ;-)

Comment: In such cases, you could validate presence of instance instead of the foreign key.

Comment: I think it is more common to use null (in SQL)/nil (in ruby) to represent no value at all; rails models allow you to specify a relationship as optional, if I recall correctly

Comment: I am doing this a lot with my current rails app. I have 3 objects and I don't set their foreign keys until after I've already created them. I also don't have any validation on the foreign key either. So to answer your question, in my opinion, I don't have any issues with running things they way you have explained.